Google BigQuery: Unsupported array of struct in stored procedure
I'm trying to define an array of struct inside a stored procedure with the intent of collecting results from a SELECT statement, which will return multiple rows of structs. Something like:
DECLARE my_array ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING,STRING,STRING>> DEFAULT NULL;
SET my_array = (SELECT ARRAY (
SELECT AS STRUCT id, type, name FROM `mytable` where company=0));

But BigQuery fails with error:

Error validating procedure body (add OPTIONS(strict_mode=false) to
suppress): Unsupported variable type:
ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING,STRING,STRING>>

Array of struct is supported in BigQuery as per documentation. So why this error? Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

The BigQuery does support ARRAY of STRUCT, but Declaring DEFAULT NULL within the stored procedure in BigQuery is NOT supported. As per this Documentation, the default value for an array cannot be NULL or contain any NULL elements. So, you cannot declare ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING, STRING>> with DEFAULT NULL.
As a workaround, you can try using the
ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, STRING, STRING>>  DEFAULT [ ];

Your comment on default array value is correct, but that's not the problem here. I tried both with default values ([]) and without default values. Get the same error.

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
